# Turn on and off custom post type from admin?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, deactivation

Is it possible to "deactivate" a custom post type and then later if you feel like using it again you can simple "activate" it again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, custom post types are registered *on the fly*, on every request. So you can create an option, say `active_custom_post_types` and check for that before you register the post type.

Pseudo-code:

```
$possible_cpts = array( 'book', 'portfolio' );
$active_cpts   = get_option( 'active_custom_post_types' );

if ( ! empty ( $active_cpts ) && is_array( $active_cpts ) )
{
    foreach ( $active_cpts as $cpt )
    {
         if ( in_array( $cpt, $possible_cpts ) )
            register_post_type( $cpt, get_args_from_somewhere() );
    }
}
```